# Issue after TL update, february 9, 2017, \RequirePackage{expl3}

Tags: expl3, updating, texlive-2016

Before update TL was working fine. After update got the error:

> Package l3sort Error: This package is obsolete --- use 'expl3'
>   instead. use 'expl3' instead}\@ehc

l3* packages were updated.

How to get back to older l3 packages? or how to tell TL people about it?

I use these packages:

```
 \documentclass[ebook,openany]{memoir}

 \settypeblocksize{43pc}{27pc}{*}%{38pc}{27pc}{*}%{43pc}{27pc}

 \setlrmargins{0.75in}{*}{*} \setulmargins{6pc}{*}{*}%{6pc}

 \setheadfoot{13pt}{2.5pc}%{13pt}{2.5pc} \setheaderspaces{*}{2.5pc}{*}

 \checkandfixthelayout 

 \fixpdflayout 

 \usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}  %
  %[sc] real small caps, family pplx; [osf] small caps, oldstyle digits
 in text, family pplj 

\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm} % Euler math

 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

 \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{amsfonts} \usepackage{amssymb}

 \usepackage{csquotes} \usepackage[font=normalsize]{idxlayout} 

 \usepackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{matrix}  \usetikzlibrary{cd}

 \usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}  \usepackage{graphicx}

 \usepackage{theorem} \usepackage{float}

 \usepackage[sort=use,toc,style=long3col]{glossaries}

 \usepackage[greek,spanish,es-lcroman]{babel} \usepackage{wasysym}

 %emoticons :) 
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}


\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks = true,linkcolor = black,urlcolor  =
 blue,citecolor = blue,anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}


\usepackage{exsheets} \usepackage{calc}
```

Comment: does it not work if you do as the error message says and use `expl3` instead of l3sort?

Comment: Where should I? I don't use l3sort, maybe some package. I think is some bug in the updated package.

Comment: This morning I update in my Ubuntu system and got the error. Later went to my Mac Os X, compile the sme file and was Ok, then update TL and got the error.

Comment: presumably a package that you are loading is written to require l3sort, but as you have shown no example hard to guess which that might be

Comment: As a workaround until a better solution comes up you can add `\expandafter\def\csname ver@l3sort.sty\endcsname{}` at the begin of your document. This will prevent that l3sort is loaded. You will perhaps have to load expl3 instead.

Comment: exsheets loads l3sort. You should notify the author. Using my code above before should solve the problem.

Comment: Please, don't add code as a block quote, but rather paste it, select it and click the `{}` button (or hit Control-K).

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer, however I was using exsheets up to this morning, before the update!

Comment: Well sure the update changed things. This can happen. When exsheets has been updated too the error will disappear.

Comment: I just see exsheets updated yesterday, maybe is not in texlive yet!

Comment: I have sent the updated version to CTAN a few hours ago. This should be fixed soon…

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is a temporary package dependency hickup.

Comment: Thanks @clemens, then it is better to wait the TL update than to download and install the package?

Comment: yes. Just use @UlrikeFischer's code in the meantime

Comment: @UlrikeFischer code: \expandafter\def\csname ver@l3sort.sty\endcsname{} works fine!!